# How to disable FPO optimisation on x64 VC++ compiler

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, windbg, disassembly

Recently I started using Windbg(x64), To play with it, I have compiled(x64) a sample program using

`cl.exe ls.c /Zi /Od /GS-`

Interestingly the functions generated for the executable contain FPO optimization. Below is the snippet of the disassembly of a routine.

```
0:000> uf ls!GetDateString
ls!GetDateString:
00007ff7`459a6d00 mov     qword ptr [rsp+8],rcx
00007ff7`459a6d05 sub     rsp,88h
00007ff7`459a6d0c mov     qword ptr [rsp+58h],0
00007ff7`459a6d15 mov     qword ptr [rsp+50h],0
00007ff7`459a6d1e mov     eax,dword ptr [ls!dateType (00007ff7`45a14494)]
00007ff7`459a6d24 and     eax,1
00007ff7`459a6d27 test    eax,eax
00007ff7`459a6d29 je      ls!GetDateString+0x3e (00007ff7`459a6d3e)
```

May I know how can I disable this FPO optimization on x64 VC++ compilers. Looking at the official documentation it seems we cannot disable it via /Oy- switch
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kxx5t2c.aspx

> /Oy enables frame-pointer omission and /Oy- disables omission. /Oy is
>   available only in x86 compilers.

I am wondering if this flag is only available for x86, then how come the x64 windows routines like FileTimeToSystemTime has FPO disabled!

```
0:000> uf .
KERNELBASE!FileTimeToSystemTime:
00007ffc`a03ad120 mov     qword ptr [rsp+18h],rbx
00007ffc`a03ad125 push    rbp
00007ffc`a03ad126 mov     rbp,rsp
00007ffc`a03ad129 sub     rsp,40h
00007ffc`a03ad12d mov     rax,qword ptr [KERNELBASE!_security_cookie (00007ffc`a0515000)]
00007ffc`a03ad134 xor     rax,rsp
00007ffc`a03ad137 mov     qword ptr [rbp-8],rax
00007ffc`a03ad13b mov     eax,dword ptr [rcx]
00007ffc`a03ad13d mov     rbx,rdx
00007ffc`a03ad140 mov     dword ptr [rbp-20h],eax
00007ffc`a03ad143 mov     eax,dword ptr [rcx+4]
00007ffc`a03ad146 mov     dword ptr [rbp-1Ch],eax
```

Comment: *"how come the x64 windows routines like FileTimeToSystemTime has FPO disabled!"* - The OS is not compiled using the same compiler that ships as part of Visual Studio.

Comment: Why do you want to disable frame-pointer omission?

Comment: @RossRidge I really don't want to disable frame pointer omission. But just wondering how is the x64 build of windows binaries has FPO disabled. I am looking for some kind of compiler flag that might have caused this. I am fine with FPO optimization.

Comment: The Microsoft x64 ABI does not require functions to have frame pointer unless the function dynamically allocate space on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

In x64 if you are using the function `__alloca()` `(allocate memory in stack)`
then ebp is used as frame pointer otherwise ebp is a general purpose register ebp is not used as frame pointer
if ebp is used as frame pointer then unwind info may contain

```
UWOP_PUSH_NONVOL reg: rbp and UWOP_SET_FPREG
```

sample src compiled with  `cl /Zi /Od /GS-  test.cpp`
compiled from a 32 bit machine using windows sdk environment

```
@call "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\setenv.cmd" /x64 /RELEASE
```

src used

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
__int64 wtfisfpo(__int64 a , __int64 b ) {
  char *foo = (char *)_alloca(0x20);
  *foo = 'b';
  printf("%c\n",foo);  
  return (b+a);
} 
int main(void) {
  printf("%I64x\n", wtfisfpo(4,9));
  return 1;
}
```

disassembled with windbg in 32 bit machine loading the exe as dump 
windbg -z test.exe

```
0:000> uf test!wtfisfpo
test!wtfisfpo [xxxx\test.cpp @ 4]:
    4 00000001`40001020 4889542410      mov     qword ptr [rsp+10h],rdx
    4 00000001`40001025 48894c2408      mov     qword ptr [rsp+8],rcx
    4 00000001`4000102a 55              push    rbp
    4 00000001`4000102b 4883ec30        sub     rsp,30h
    4 00000001`4000102f 488d6c2420      lea     rbp,[rsp+20h]
    5 00000001`40001034 8b0424          mov     eax,dword ptr [rsp]
    5 00000001`40001037 b820000000      mov     eax,20h
    5 00000001`4000103c 482be0          sub     rsp,rax
    5 00000001`4000103f 488d442420      lea     rax,[rsp+20h]
    5 00000001`40001044 8b08            mov     ecx,dword ptr [rax]
    5 00000001`40001046 48894500        mov     qword ptr [rbp],rax
    6 00000001`4000104a 488b4500        mov     rax,qword ptr [rbp]
    6 00000001`4000104e c60062          mov     byte ptr [rax],62h
    7 00000001`40001051 488b5500        mov     rdx,qword ptr [rbp]
    7 00000001`40001055 488d0d907c0100  lea     rcx,[test!__xt_z+0x12c (00000001`40018cec)]
    7 00000001`4000105c e8cf000000      call    test!printf (00000001`40001130)
    8 00000001`40001061 488b4520        mov     rax,qword ptr [rbp+20h]
    8 00000001`40001065 488b4d28        mov     rcx,qword ptr [rbp+28h]
    8 00000001`40001069 4803c8          add     rcx,rax
    8 00000001`4000106c 488bc1          mov     rax,rcx
    9 00000001`4000106f 488d6510        lea     rsp,[rbp+10h]
    9 00000001`40001073 5d              pop     rbp
    9 00000001`40001074 c3              ret
```

the unwind info details of this function

```
0:000> .fnent test!wtfisfpo
Debugger function entry 00000000`000d39a0 for:
xxxx\test.cpp(4)
(00000001`40001020)   test!wtfisfpo   |  (00000001`40001080)   test!main
Exact matches:
    test!wtfisfpo (int64, int64)

BeginAddress      = 00000000`00001020
EndAddress        = 00000000`00001075
UnwindInfoAddress = 00000000`0001c1b8

Unwind info at 00000001`4001c1b8, a bytes
  version 1, flags 0, prolog 14, codes 3
  frame reg 5 (rbp), frame offs 20h
  00: offs 14, unwind op 3, op info 2   UWOP_SET_FPREG.
  01: offs f, unwind op 2, op info 5    UWOP_ALLOC_SMALL.
  02: offs b, unwind op 0, op info 5    UWOP_PUSH_NONVOL reg: rbp.
```

as to the comment why rbp is used **maybe** the function was compiled as an assembly routine like this

```
include ksamd64.inc
.CODE
  main PROC 
    call sample
  main ENDP

  sample PROC FRAME
    push_reg rbp
    set_frame rbp, 0h
    .endprolog
    add rsp, 0
    pop rbp
    ret
  sample ENDP
END
```

assembled with

```
@call "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\setenv.cmd" /x64 /RELEASE
ml64.exe /Zi 64bitasm.asm /link /subsystem:console /defaultlib:kernel32.lib /entry:main /RELEASE
```

and the relevent disassembly

```
0:000> x 64bitasm!*
00000001`40002058 64bitasm!$xdatasym = 0x01 ''
00000001`40001000 64bitasm!main (void)
00000001`40001005 64bitasm!sample (void)
0:000> uf 64bitasm!sample
64bitasm!sample [\64bitasm.asm @ 7]:
    7 00000001`40001005 55              push    rbp
    9 00000001`40001006 488bec          mov     rbp,rsp
   11 00000001`40001009 4883c400        add     rsp,0
   12 00000001`4000100d 5d              pop     rbp
   13 00000001`4000100e c3              ret
0:000> uf 64bitasm!main
64bitasm!main [\64bitasm.asm @ 3]:
    3 00000001`40001000 e800000000      call    64bitasm!sample (00000001`40001005)
    7 00000001`40001005 55              push    rbp
    9 00000001`40001006 488bec          mov     rbp,rsp
   11 00000001`40001009 4883c400        add     rsp,0
   12 00000001`4000100d 5d              pop     rbp
   13 00000001`4000100e c3              ret
```

Comment: Cloud you please explain then how come x64 version of KERNELBASE!FileTimeToSystemTime is have rbp?

Comment: may be compiled as assembly ? with set_frame ebp ,0 see the edit you ca n do it too